# MongoDB Java API Query UPDATE include word

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem. I need include one word in the value from the field: "name".
For example:

```
    {name : "Apple inc."}
```

I would like add the word "Company".

```
{name : "Company Apple inc."}
```

But, I can't. Where is it my issue?

```
collectionCOMPANIES.updateMany(

        new Document("$where", "true")
            , 

            new Document("$set", new Document("name","Company + $name")
                    ));
```

If I do this, return:

```
{name : "Company + $name"}
```

Thanks.

******* UPDATE SOLUTION******

For the final code In java this is:

```
collectionCOMPANIES.find().forEach(new Block<Document>() {
        public void apply(final Document document) {
            final Document DocuNew = new Document();
            DocuNew.putAll(document);



            DocuNew.put("name", "Company " + document.get("name")); 


            newcollection.insertOne(DocuNew);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
db.collectionCOMPANIES.find().snapshot().forEach( function (doc) {
doc.name = "Company " + doc.name; 
db.collectionCOMPANIES.save(doc); 
});
```

For this I am using `snapshot` provided by mongodb. you can read more about it [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/)

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't because I'm new user but when I have  a reputation the first step that I will do it is!

Comment: you can still accept the answer. Hit the arrow to the left of my answer to make it green